# Conditional column data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to add a column to a table that will have data based on another table. Today I use MATCH and INDEX to achieve this but I think there must be a better way. My manual formulas are prone to have errors and its hard to make a template out of. When using both tables I want to create the column with the red letters/numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Lookup With INDEX/MATCH in Excel (Structured) Tables

- Usually, there's nothing that can beat an `INDEX/MATCH` formula. It's just a bit tricky in Excel (structured) tables:

  ```
  =IFNA(INDEX(Table2,MATCH([@Size],Table2[Size],0),MATCH("Type "&[@Type]&" Code",Table2[#Headers],0)),"")
  ```

  or more readable:

  ```
  =IFNA(
      INDEX(
          Table2,
          MATCH([@Size],Table2[Size],0),
          MATCH("Type "&[@Type]&" Code",Table2[#Headers],0)
          ),
      ""
      )
  ```

  *Adjust the name of the table!*
- If you have Microsoft 365, instead of `MATCH`, you could use `XMATCH` to get rid of the 3rd parameters (the zeros):

  ```
  =IFNA(INDEX(Table2,XMATCH([@Size],Table2[Size]),XMATCH("Type "&[@Type]&" Code",Table2[#Headers])),"")
  ```

  *Excel (structured) tables do not support spilling formulas.*
- Best clear the contents of the `Type Code` column before entering the formula into its first row only. The remaining rows will get populated automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the second table is always like that Size, Type 1 code, Type 2 code, Type 3 code => you can use the below formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(C4,G:J,D4+1,FALSE)
```

With the above formula you can use `VLOOKUP` on size and then for the column we will put the `type value + 1`. Since "Type 3 Code" is always the 4th column, then 3+1=4.

[image: Example]